# applying multiple bootstrap classes on a single class

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this button on multiple places in my code

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit ">Sign up!</button>
```

can I somehow define a single class for that like below?

```
<button class="myButton" type="submit">Sign up!</button>
```

and "myButton" will be equivalent to "btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary".

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you use SASS, although ***it is not recommended***.

```
.myButton {
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .btn-block;
    @extend .btn-lg;
    @extend .btn-primary.
}
```

You can read more about extend [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/). Also, it's worth reading [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/extend/approach/) page on the bootstrap docs.